# Append one item from an array to one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, underscore.js

I have a bunch of content on a page, including some sections like below, but interspersed with other content sections.

```
<main>
  <section class="module content content-fact">
    <div class="container" id="0"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="module content content-fact">
    <div class="container" id="1"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="module content content-fact">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

I have an array of random facts that I have randomized using `Underscore.js` `-->`  `_.shuffle()` function.

```
const spiderFacts = [
    "Spiders are not insects. They are arachnids. Both arachnids and insects are arthropods.",
    "Spiders eat about 200 kilograms of insects per hectare per year.",
    "Spiders inhabit just about every corner of the globe.",
    "Charlotte in E.B. White’s Charlotte’s Web was a barn orbweaver spider, <em>Araneus cavaticus<em>."
]

const randomSpiderFacts = _.shuffle(spiderFacts);
```

I want to append a `p` element containing one random fact to each `section.content-fact > div.container` on the page, but I'm stuck on how to do that.

So far I have...

```
for (var fact in randomSpiderFacts) {
  var newElement = document.createElement('p');
  newElement.className = "fact";
  newElement.innerHTML = randomSpiderFacts[fact];
  $('.content-fact > .container').appendChild(newElement);
}
```

I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way but am not sure how to get back on the right track. Can anyone help ?

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to do this and hope I explained what I'm trying to do clearly.

Comment: One question , in your case , on every loop one fact will be append to all those fact-divs , is that what you want , or not ?

Comment: Yes, one fact in each fact div!

Comment: didn't understand, are you trying to find how to append or how to put the text in all p elements? sorry didn't understand your question

Comment: I'm trying to one item from the randomSpiderFacts array to each fact div. I.e. randomSpiderFacts[1] would go in the first fact div, randomSpiderFacts[2] would go in the second fact div, randomSpiderFacts[3] would go in the third div, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is clean expet the appendChild() function , this is not a part of jquery

Also each fact will be append to each .fact div , so reverse the function by looping the div's and append to each div a fact content using [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

See below snippet :

```js
const spiderFacts = [
    "Spiders are not insects. They are arachnids. Both arachnids and insects are arthropods.",
    "Spiders eat about 200 kilograms of insects per hectare per year.",
    "Spiders inhabit just about every corner of the globe.",
    "Charlotte in E.B. White’s Charlotte’s Web was a barn orbweaver spider, <em>Araneus cavaticus<em>."
]

const randomSpiderFacts = _.shuffle(spiderFacts);

$('.content-fact > .container').each(function(i,el){
  // check if not exceeding the array so return empty string
  var factContent = randomSpiderFacts[i] ? randomSpiderFacts[i] : "";
  $("<p>").addClass("fact").html(factContent).appendTo(el);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<section class="module content content-fact">
  <div class="container" id="0"></div>
</section>

<section class="module content content-fact">
  <div class="container" id="1"></div>
</section>

<section class="module content content-fact">
  <div class="container"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Also, `for..in` loops are not meant to be used for traversing arrays, you should use `for..of` instead

Comment: Thank you both! When I run this code though it appends ALL the facts to each fact div. But I only want one fact per fact div. Should I for loop through the divs somehow to achieve this?

Comment: That's it. Thank you @BooBerr'ita! It seems obvious now :)

Comment: You're Welcome @Kait , :)